# Android studio - ScheduledExecutorService странная ошибка

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-edittext, таймер, schedule

Делаю выделение определенного синтаксиса через `ScheduledExecutorService`, со следующим синтаксисом:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executor.newSingleThreadScheduleExecutor();
executorService.schedule(new syntaxLight(s, editText), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

где `s` - `Editable`, а `editText` - `EditText`. Все это сделано в `TextWatcher`, когда же наступает 2 секунда, то приложение зависает до тех пор, пока я не нажал enter или не был набран 24 символ. Странно, но это так.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно дождаться выполнение всех потоков в Executor и завершить его:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public MyRunnable(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.schedule(new MyRunnable(3, 2), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```